# How to convert text to json format

Tags: python, json

I have a text file that contains data in json format

```
{"Header":
{
"name":"test"},
"params":{
"address":"myhouse"
}
}
```

I am trying to read it from a python file and convert it to json format. I have tried with both yaml and json libraries, and, with both libraries, it converts it to json format, but it also converts the double quotes to single quotes

Is there any way of parsing it into a json format, but keeping the double quotes?

I dont think using a replace call is a valid option, as it will also replace single quotes that are part of the data

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the current output and the desired one. Taking into consideration that Pythor represents string with single quotes. If you would like to print it as json object you can dump it and it will be correct.

Comment: Single quotes is just how Python shows strings, they are still strings. If you do a `json.dump()` to convert back to `json` it will use double quotes.

Comment: `json` standard requires double quotes, from the [standard](http://www.json.org/): "A value can be a string in double quotes"

Comment: If it's a valid json data, have you tried just changing the file extension?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `json.load` to load a json object from a file.

```
import json
with open("file.json", "r") as f:
    obj = json.load(f)
```

The resulting json object delimits strings with `'` rather than `"`, but you can easily use a `replace` call at that point.

```
In [6]: obj
Out[6]: {'Header': {'name': 'test'}, 'params': {'address': 'myhouse'}}
```

EDIT:

Though I misunderstood the question at first, you can use `json.dumps` to write a string-encoding of the json object that uses double quotes as the standard requires.

```
In [10]: json.dumps(obj)                                                                       
Out[10]: '{"params": {"address": "myhouse"}, "Header": {"na\'me": "test"}}'
```

It's unclear what you're trying to do though, as if you're trying to read the json into a Python object, it doesn't matter what string delimiters are used; if you're trying to read your valid json into a Python string, you can just read the file without any libraries.

Comment: This is not `json` but `python`'s representation of a `dict` with `str`. Python's repr of a string uses single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
import json
with open("file.json", "r") as f:
    obj = json.load(f)

with open("file.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(obj, f, indent = 4[, ensure_ascii = False]) # if your string has some unicode characters, let ensure_ascii to be False.
```